# Using Scrollify on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

How do I use the scrollify library to transition down a webpage to a specific section of a page after clicking a link.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#1" class="link">this is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" class="link">this is another link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" class="link">and another link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each one of these upon click will send the user to a certain section of the webpage shown below. Right now without scrollify, there is no soft transition to each part.

```
<h3 class="season" id="1"><span class="seasontext">SS17</span></h3>
<h3 class="season" id="2"><span class="seasontext">SS17</span></h3>
<h3 class="season" id="3"><span class="seasontext">SS17</span></h3>
```

This is the scrollify template but I'm not quite sure how to access links seperately and how to use the transition.

```
$.scrollify({
    section : "link",
    interstitialSection : "",
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    scrollSpeed: 1100,
    offset : 0,
    scrollbars: true,
    standardScrollElements: "",
    setHeights: true,
    overflowScroll: true,
    updateHash: true,
    touchScroll:true,
    before:function() {},
    after:function() {},
    afterResize:function() {},
    afterRender:function() {}
});

$.scrollify.move("#season");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to write a click event to achieve this like below.

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  var moveTo = $(this).attr('href');
  $.scrollify("move",moveTo);
});
```

Hope it helps.